# Suppress symfony 4 response body in phpunit test

Tags: phpunit, symfony4

I am migrating a Silex app to Symfony Flex and everything is working so far, except that when I run the phpunit tests I get the response body output into the phpunit output.

ie.

```
> bin/phpunit
#!/usr/bin/env php
PHPUnit 6.5.13 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Testing unit
.......<http://data.nobelprize.org/resource/laureate/914> a <http://data.nobelprize.org/terms/Laureate> , <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person> ;
<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "Malala Yousafzai" ;
<http://data.nobelprize.org/terms/laureateAward> <http://data.nobelprize.org/resource/laureateaward/974> ;
<http://data.nobelprize.org/terms/nobelPrize> <http://data.nobelprize.org/resource/nobelprize/Peace/2014> ;
```

the entire RDF document then

```
 .                                                            8 / 8 (100%)

 Time: 1.07 seconds, Memory: 14.00MB

 OK (8 tests, 71 assertions)

 Generating code coverage report in Clover XML format ... done
```

So it is working fine, but I can't figure out how to disable this output?

The request is simply

```
$this->client->request('GET', "/nobel_914.ttl", [], [], ['HTTP_ACCEPT' => $request_mime]);
$this->assertEquals(200, $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode(), "GET should be allowed.");
$response = $this->client->getResponse();
$charset = $response->getCharset();
```

etc.

and the client is setup in a base class like this

```
class MyAppTestBase extends WebTestCase
{
  /**
   * @var \Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client
   */
  protected $client;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function setUp() {
      parent::setUp();
      $this->client = static::createClient();
      $this->client->catchExceptions(false);
  }
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but this is new to me. I am running in the 'test' environment and with 'debug' == false.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Here is full execution if you want to see it. 
https://ci.appveyor.com/project/acoburn/static-ldp/builds/20444722#L302

Comment: Additionally here is the PR with all the code changes I am implementing. https://github.com/trellis-ldp/static-ldp/pull/39 You can see the test code, etc in case that helps.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `WebTestCase`, but since it's an integration test or functional test rather than a unit test, you could always buffer the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this was probably a problem all along but just started being exposed in the switch from Silex to Symfony Flex.

We were streaming responses via

```
$filename = $this->path;
$stream = function () use ($filename) {
    readfile($filename);
};
return new StreamedResponse($stream, 200, $res->headers->all());
```

and the `readfile` was throwing the content to the output buffer. Switching the `readfile` to `file_get_contents` resolved this

```
$filename = $this->path;
$stream = function () use ($filename) {
    file_get_contents($filename);
};
return new StreamedResponse($stream, 200, $res->headers->all());
```